# Firefox abort content.location load

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox extension. Inside my extension I use:

```
content.location.assign(url)
```

Depending on the users input `content.location.assign(url)` gets called again after a short time. It seems like my 2nd assign gets ignored. I'm looking for a way to abort the in process request to push trough the current one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, try using either of this methods:-

```
reload(forceget)
```

Reload the document from the current URL. forceget is a boolean, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

```
replace(url)
```

Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

Comment: could you please provide any example for reload(forceget)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use content.location to load a new page into the browser; instead use `loadURI(url[, referrer[, postData[, allowThirdPartyFixup]]])` to load a page and `BrowserStop()` to cancel a load.